# Codeception handle expected UserException

Tags: yii2, codeception

Running a function test as below for an application in Yii2 framework.

```
public function checkEmptyToken2(FunctionalTester $I)
{
    $I->amOnRoute('site/verify-email', ['token' => '']);
    $I->canSee('Email verify token did not come through for some reason');
}
```

Results in an error as below.

```
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v4.2.1
Powered by PHPUnit 8.5.27

Frontend\tests.functional Tests (1) -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
E VerifyEmailCest: Check empty token2 (0.01s)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1) VerifyEmailCest: Check empty token2
 Test  tests/functional/VerifyEmailCest.php:checkEmptyToken2
                                         
  [yii\base\UserException] Email verify token did not come through for some reason.
            You can either copy/paste the verification email again OR
            request a new verification email from the <a href="/index-test.php/site/login">Login</a> page.
                                          
Scenario Steps:

 1. $I->amOnRoute("site/verify-email",{"token":""}) at tests/functional/VerifyEmailCest.php:41

#1  /data/www/frontend/models/VerifyEmailForm.php:38
#2  /data/www/frontend/controllers/SiteController.php:345
#3  frontend\controllers\SiteController->actionVerifyEmail
#4  /data/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php:57
#5  /data/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php:178
#6  /data/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php:552
#7  /data/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php:103
#8  /data/www/vendor/symfony/browser-kit/Client.php:405
#9  Codeception\Module\Yii2->amOnRoute
#10 /data/www/frontend/tests/_support/_generated/FunctionalTesterActions.php:661


Time: 718 ms, Memory: 16.00 MB

There was 1 error:

---------

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

I expect the error to be exactly that! All I want Codeception to do is to simply ignore it and move on so I can check for the error text in "canSee". I tried using try/catch statement and that results in a different error. Tried using "expectException" and that did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

The codeception module will only handle subclasses of `yii\web\HttpException` as part of the normal request flow.
If you are throwing a `yii\base\UserException` then the status code will always be 500 as it is for any other exception.

While I doubt that throwing `UserException`s that do not extend the `HttpException` the Yii error handler supports it. I'll update the codeception module to support it as well.